# Pandas DataFrame extract between one START word and multiple STOP words

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I want to write a regular expression to extract a pattern from Pandas DataFrame using str.extract that extracts the first match of the pattern found between a START word and ends with one of the two possible STOP words.

example# 1: START hello there STOP WORD

example# 2: START Good morning ANOTHER DELIMITER

In the first case, I want to return 'hello there' , and in the second case 'Good morning'

If there is only one stop word at the end, like in example 1, the following regular expression within str.extract works. But how do I combine two STOP words?

r'(?s)START(.*?)STOP\s+WORD'

Comment: What have you tried? Include it in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex alternation:

```regex
\bSTART\s+(.*?)\s+(?:STOP WORD|ANOTHER DELIMITER)\b
```

Pandas code:

```py
df["match"] = df["col"].str.extract(r'\bSTART\s+(.*?)\s+(?:STOP WORD|ANOTHER DELIMITER)\b')
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. What if one of the the STOP WORDs is three newline characters '\n\n\n'? So my text that I am trying to extract can have new line character. So I enforce dotall (?s) at the beginning. But one of the stop word is three newline characters

 df["match"] = df["col"].str.extract(r'(?s)\bSTART\s+(.*?)\s+(?:STOP WORD|\n\n\n)\b')

Comment: In that case, use: `(?s)\bSTART\s+(.*?)\s+(?:STOP WORD\b|\n\n\n)`

Comment: Is there a way to extract between both multiple start and end words?

Comment: @asd Your comment strikes me as being too long/different for a follow-up here.  Maybe ask that in a new question.

Comment: Sure : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68541558/pandas-extract-between-multiple-start-words-and-multiple-stop-words