# Pandas extract between multiple Start words and multiple stop words

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-re

Following on from [Pandas DataFrame extract between one START word and multiple STOP words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68417877/pandas-dataframe-extract-between-one-start-word-and-multiple-stop-words), is it possible to extend the solution to multiple start words, too?
Example shouldn't be taken very literally:

```
df 
   
0   start_word1  text1 end_word1
1   start_word2  text2 end_word2
```

Expected output

```
df 
   
0   text1 
1   text2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [non-capturing groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) to define the start/stop words alternatives:

```
df['COLUMN_NAME'].str.extract('(?:start_word1|start_word2)\s+(.*)\s+(?:end_word1|end_word2)')
```